# decrease the magnitude of a float?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to know how to decrease the magnitude of a number. In math, magnitude of a number is the distance from 0.  I know that you can get the absolute value of a number with Mathf.Abs() but I'd like to know how to subtract the number to get it closer to zero and retain its sign.

I know that I can use

```
if (number > 0)
    number -= increment;
else if (number < 0)
    number += increment;
```

but I am wondering if there is a function in C# or Unity that does the same as the above.

Comment: Devs are unlikely to clutter the library with such circumstantial functions, when they can easily be written using other basic functions such as `Math.Abs` and `Math.Sign`.

Comment: I don't understand your exact question but you can change your code to this: `number += Mathf.Sign(number) * -1 * increment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number = Mathf.MoveTowards(number, 0, increment);`

Comment: For non-Unity people reading this: this is a Unity library, so it won't work in vanilla C#.